# JQuery : how to undo changes made on DOM ?

Tags: jquery

I have modified the price attribute on select change .

How can i get it back to normal price on else condition ?

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
    $('#select_1').on('change', function() {
    var visit_time_val=$(this).val();

    if(visit_time_val==93 || visit_time_val==95)
    {
        var adult_price=26;
        var child_price=10;

        $('#select_15 option:nth-child(2)').attr("price",adult_price);
        $('#select_15 option:nth-child(3)').attr("price",adult_price*2);
        $('#select_15 option:nth-child(4)').attr("price",adult_price*3);
        $('#select_15 option:nth-child(5)').attr("price",adult_price*4);   

        $('#select_3 option:nth-child(2)').attr("price",child_price);   
        $('#select_3 option:nth-child(3)').attr("price",child_price*2);  
        $('#select_3 option:nth-child(4)').attr("price",child_price*3);  


    }
    else
    {
        //back to prices setted in db
    }
     });
});
```

Comment: Could you post codes what you tried in else block?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
    var previous;

    $("#select_1").one('focus', function () {
        // Store the current value on focus and on change
        previous = this.value;
    }).change(function() {
        var visit_time_val=$(this).val();

    if(visit_time_val==93 || visit_time_val==95)
    {
        var adult_price=26;
        var child_price=10;

        $('#select_15 option:nth-child(2)').attr("price",adult_price);
        $('#select_15 option:nth-child(3)').attr("price",adult_price*2);
        $('#select_15 option:nth-child(4)').attr("price",adult_price*3);
        $('#select_15 option:nth-child(5)').attr("price",adult_price*4);   

        $('#select_3 option:nth-child(2)').attr("price",child_price);   
        $('#select_3 option:nth-child(3)').attr("price",child_price*2);  
        $('#select_3 option:nth-child(4)').attr("price",child_price*3);  


    }
    else
    {
        //back to prices setted in db
        $(this).val(previous );
    }
    });
```

Comment: what i want is //back to original #select_15 and #select_3

Comment: assign one of these values after page loads to 'previous' and don't change it on focus as I did.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the value in the data attributes of the Select tag, So that you can use that value.

```
<select id="select_1" data-selectedvalue="10">
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
<option selected>10</option>
</select>

jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {
    $('#select_1').on('change', function() {
    var visit_time_val=$(this).val();

    if(visit_time_val==93 || visit_time_val==95)
    {
        var adult_price=26;
        var child_price=10;

        $('#select_15 option:nth-child(2)').attr("price",adult_price);
        $('#select_15 option:nth-child(3)').attr("price",adult_price*2);
        $('#select_15 option:nth-child(4)').attr("price",adult_price*3);
        $('#select_15 option:nth-child(5)').attr("price",adult_price*4);   

        $('#select_3 option:nth-child(2)').attr("price",child_price);   
        $('#select_3 option:nth-child(3)').attr("price",child_price*2);  
        $('#select_3 option:nth-child(4)').attr("price",child_price*3);  


    }
    else
    {
        $(this).val($(this).data("selectedvalue"));
    }
     });
});
```